# PHP: Why does true is equal to -1?

Tags: php

```
echo (true == -1 ? "I'm a little bit surprising" : "Life is easy");
```

gives

```
I'm a little bit surprising
```

May someone explain me why is -1 equal to true?
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp should explain how, not sure about why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just read [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), it says:

When converting to bool, the following values are considered **false**:

- the boolean false itself
- the integer 0 (zero)
- the floats 0.0 and -0.0 (zero)
- the empty string, and the string "0"
- an array with zero elements
- the special type NULL (including unset variables)
- SimpleXML objects created from attributeless empty elements, i.e. elements which have neither children nor attributes.

Every other value is considered **true** (including any resource and NAN).